# Proguard runtime error with external Admob jar

Tags: android, jar, admob, proguard

signed app gives error!

my app uses an external Admob jar, however proguard is touching the jar:

the jar file is located at /libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1.jar

Thank you

LogCat error:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Warning: com.google.ads.m: can't find referenced class  
com.google.ads.internal.state.AdState
Warning: com.google.ads.m: can't find referenced class com.google.ads.internal.state.AdState
  You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
     You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

which is inside the jar-file

Config proguard-project.txt:

```
-libraryjars /libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1.jar

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
public <init>(android.content.Context);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
public void *(android.view.View);
public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
public static <fields>;
}
```

after adding

```
-keep public class com.google.ads.**
```

to the file, the eclipse console gives still the following error:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Note: there were 160 duplicate class definitions.
Warning: com.google.ads.m: can't find referenced class     
com.google.ads.internal.state.AdState
Warning: com.google.ads.m: can't find referenced class    
com.google.ads.internal.state.AdState
You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040226/progaurd-returned-with-error-code-1

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But this does not work for the e.g. Dropbox Sdkor other external jars. These will be touched or altered by the proguard

Comment: Sounds like you don't want proguard to alter the library files. You should add `-keep public class com.google.ads.**` for the AdMob SDK jar, and something similar for the other jars, so these classes don't get renamed.

Comment: did it but still comes the error, see edit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just added the

```
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
```

to the proguard-project.txt file and the signed apk works fine!
this is recommended (like Eric said before) here: [Proguard can't find referenced class com.google.ads.internal.state.AdState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040226/progaurd-returned-with-error-code-1)

Comment: that really works for me..I ha also added as per Eric Leichtenschlag Nov 2 at 16:55 comment. Thanks to both of you..

Comment: This code signed the application but the admob ads did appear and gave classnotfoundexception but @peterdk code worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on It seems that you need to add these 2 items to the proguard config :

```
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
-keep class com.google.ads.**  {*;}
```

Answer (score 0):

-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
here secure the ads class
if you want to secure your class then add com.pkgname.**